# How to make python code run for more words

Tags: python, python-3.x

Code only runs for one word and not the whole string

```
def silly_case(in_string):
    firstlet =  in_string[0]
    firstlet = firstlet.lower()
    upperpart =  in_string[1:]
    upperpart = upperpart.upper()
    in_string =  firstlet + upperpart
    return in_string

silly_string = silly_case("This is a string")
print(silly_string)
```

Comment: What's the expected output?

Comment: It is supposed to out put the same string but the first letter of each word should be lowercase and the rest should all be uppercase. Ex, tHIS iS a sTRING. Currently only the first word is outputted correctly whilst the rest remain the same. Thank you for the quick response!

Answer (score 5):

You can use the built-in functions `title` and `swapcase`:

```
>>> "This is a string".title().swapcase()
'tHIS iS a sTRING'
```

Or to fix your code, you should split the string into words and then iterate through them before you apply your case logic on each word:

```
def silly_case(in_string):
    words = []
    for word in in_string.split():
        firstlet =  word[0]
        firstlet = firstlet.lower()
        upperpart =  word[1:]
        upperpart = upperpart.upper()
        words.append(firstlet + upperpart)
    return ' '.join(words)

silly_string = silly_case("This is a string")
print(silly_string)
```